# Any simpler solution to add horizontal lines above and below the: Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables, List of Abbreviations?

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I have refined but failed iterations regarding the same:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% For Content

{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\tableofcontents
{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\clearpage

% For Figures

{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\listoffigures
{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\clearpage

% For Tables

{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\listoftables
{\rule[0.1cm]{\textwidth}{2.5pt}}
\clearpage

\chapter{This is chapter-1}
\section{Having two sections, this is first one}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a MWE figure}
\label{fig:dum}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[1]

\section{And this one is second}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{This is a MWE table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
V1 & V2 & V3 & V4 & V5 \\
\midrule
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

The problem is that these commands are creating lines before the header line and after the context of Content, Figures, Tables etc.

I need these lines to be exactly at the centre and exactly above and below the header content and not after the content.

I've explored similar questions but failed for simplified solution.

Also updated this question with MWE. Hope it will help to understand the problem better.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want a "ruled title". That is, a rule, then "Table of Contents", then another rule, then the actual Table of Contents. Similarly for List of Figures and List of Tables. Visually, somewhat similar to the [`memoir` class](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/memoir) (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nlzd.png)), only left-aligning the title. Is that correct?

Comment: We need a lot of more information, e.g., the used class, already used packages for configuration of headings (e.g. `titlesec`) or table of contents etc. (e.g. `etoc`, `tocloft`, `tocbasic`). Do you want such lines also for the headings of other chapters/sections? As always it would be advisable to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that shows all these information and also can be used to reproduce your problem and test our ideas.

Comment: Without more information and a MWE, I would guess you are searching for something like style `Sonny` of [package `fncychap`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap`)

Comment: @Werner Yes you caught the problem correctly..any solution ???

Comment: @cabohah I've now updated it with MWE.

Comment: @KumarGauravSagar: Do you want that style for *all* your chapters? Or just for the introductory ones (ToC/LoF/LoT)? I'd hope it should apply to all, for consistency.

Comment: @Werner For chapter I've already used package: fncychap. The issue is to add these lines only on: TOC, LOF, LOT.

Comment: I've already told, that you can use package `fncychap` and that using such packages is relevant for the answer. So please show, what you are using for the other chapters, so we have a chance to see, why it does not work for ToC, LoF etc. which are also chapters.

Comment: @cabohah I'm using : \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
By default there are NO lines in ToC, LoF, LoT.

Comment: And why don't you show this in your MWE at least after getting the comment, that you could use `fncychap` style `Sonny` to have lines above and below chapter headings and also the note, that already using a package for chapter headings would be relevant? It is in your interest to provide helpers with all the information they need and to make it as easy as possible for them to help. BTW: Your real question would be, e.g.: “How to add lines above and below not numbered chapters like the table of contents with `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with package `fncychap`. According to the [manual](https://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf)
, you can renewcommand `\DOTIS` to keep the default format and space settings and only add top rule and bottom rule for the arguments #1.

> Note the rule width have defined using `\RW` which will be changed according to the command `\ChRuleWidth{<some length>}`. In this way, the rule width will be consistent between the normal chapter and toc,lot,lof. If you don't want to this, change the `\RW` command with some length value. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
\raggedright \CTV \FmTi {\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par#1\par\rule[12pt]{\textwidth}{2pt}}\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
}
```

Here is an fully working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{2.5pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
\raggedright \CTV \FmTi {\rule{\textwidth}{\RW}\par#1\par\rule[12pt]{\textwidth}{\RW}}\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{duckuments}
\begin{document}
\duckument[toc]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Brilliant trick to probe inside the defaults....Thanks a lot...it will sail and guide my future articles & projects. \textbf{Thanks} $\times 10^{\infy}$

Comment: You're welcome.